# Pandas and Scipy TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, scipy, algorithmic-trading

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 
import math
from scipy import stats

hqm_columns = [
    'Ticker',
    'Price',
    'Number of Shares to Buy',
    'One-Year Price Return',
    'One-Year Return Percentile',
    'Six-Month Price Return',
    'Six-Month Return Percentile',
    'Three-Month Price Return',
    'Three-Month Return Percentile',
    'One-Month Price Return',
    'One-Month Return Percentile',
    'HQM Score'
]

#create the data frame using pandas
hqm_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns = hqm_columns)
#data created using iex cloud API

#calculate the percentile scores
time_periods = [
                'One-Year',
                'Six-Month',
                'Three-Month',
                'One-Month'
                ]
for row in hqm_dataframe.index:
    for time_period in time_periods:
        change_col = f'{time_period} Price Return'
        percentile_col = f'{time_period} Return Percentile'
        hqm_dataframe.loc[row, percentile_col] = stats.percentileofscore(hqm_dataframe[change_col], hqm_dataframe.loc[row, change_col])/100
```

I get the following error based on the last line of code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Areet\Documents\cs\python\algoTrading\quantMomentum2.py", line 77, in <module>
    hqm_dataframe.loc[row, percentile_col] = stats.percentileofscore(hqm_dataframe[change_col], hqm_dataframe.loc[row, change_col])/100
  File "C:\Users\Areet\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python39\site-packages\scipy\stats\stats.py", line 2017, in percentileofscore
    left = np.count_nonzero(a < score)
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'NoneType' and 'float'
```

The preceding lines of code instantiate and declare the variables being used in the line with the error. After reading about "percentileofscore" from the scipy module, I know that the parameters are an array and a float. I am unsure why it is not recognizing the data frame column as an array.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reduce this to a [mcve]—the shortest amount of code necessary to replicate the problem. (See [ask].)

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy I attempted to make it more concise but I am unsure if I did it correctly based on the link you provided.

Comment: Examine the Series that you are passing to `stats`.  I think it contains `None` elements.  You have the data, so it's your responsibility to know what it is.

Comment: @hpaulj I tested this with the isinstance() method and it returned true for being a float, that is each individual member of the array. I am guessing that the array is not recognized as a float array.

Answer (score 1):

hqm_dataframe = hqm_dataframe.infer_objects()

The above line of code will set the datatypes of columns that contain float values as datatype "float64" instead of datatype "object". After this conversion, the stats.percentileofscore function can be used to compare the values within the column.